# Eclipse breakpoint conditional skipping

Tags: eclipse

I read several posts on this but I could not fix my problem which is that eclipse skips a conditional I defined on a variable.

```
if(currentContent=="content") {
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Can you please advice what I should do for the conditional to trigger the breakpoint when the value of my string variable is equal "content".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on == with Strings. Use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

nitind's point about using .equals is important, but I think a bigger issue is that the breakpoint condition is evaluated BEFORE the line executes, not after.  I get the feeling you want to hit the breakpoint when the resulting value of "currentContent" matches your expectations AFTER the assignment, not before.

In this case, I suggest you move your breakpoint to the executable line that comes after this line.